# Webpack - 'velocity is not defined'

Tags: javascript, webpack, velocity.js

I'm using webpack along with gulp and this is my webpack config:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
var HardSourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    output: {
        publicPath: "./dist/",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/js/"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["env"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            moment: 'moment/src/moment'
        }
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery',
        $: 'jQuery',
        moment: 'moment',
        "velocity-animate": 'velocity'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HardSourceWebpackPlugin()
    ]
};
```

**scripts.js** ( This is all that's in this file )

```
import velocity from 'velocity-animate';
```

And I get this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: velocity is not defined
```

**Error on this line:**

```
module.exports = velocity;
```

Am I doing something wrong with the externals configuration?
This works for both moment.js and jQuery, but not for velocity...

I've tried

```
"velocity-animate": 'velocity'
```

and

```
"velocity-animate": 'velocity-animate'
```

and

```
"velocity-animate": '"velocity-animate"'
```

And none of these work. If the first one isn't 'velocity-animate' ( the name of the package ) then Velocity.js gets included in the script anyway. The documentation on this doesn't really explain how to properly configure this

Is it really possible that this use case is so niche that nobody on earth can explain it?

Thanks!

Comment: When do you get the error? At compile or runtime?

Comment: Runtime. Compilation goes through fine

Comment: Because you defined it as external, webpack won't bundle it with your application. You have to manually add it to your html. Please make sure that it is available in your html

Comment: It's available, and that's not the issue. I'm not even calling Velocity anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead dev of Velocity V2 here.

Doh - we'd missed updating the export of Velocity - I'll get that in later today. We're also in the process of module-ifying it, so you'll be able to import it "normally" within a Webpack project (including tree shaking etc) - that should be done in the next week or so.

Until I push an updated build the name it's exporting as is `"Velocity"` - note the capital "V" - hopefully later today it'll move over (2.0.2@beta will have the corrected name of `"velocity-animate"`).

Comment: Thanks! Would've never thought that was the problem

Comment: 2.0.2 is now on npm :-)